# When do you need to explicitly call std::move and when not in cpp?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

I'm working through Stroustrup's "Tour of C++ v2". It's certainly not a C++ beginner's book, but enjoyable.

I've had a google and look through SO but no joy on this one.

Now, I thought I understood when the compiler can utilise a move constructor, but clearly I don't. Here I show the move constructor and the function that I thought would use it. It doesn't. Only if I explicitly use std::move. Why is this? My understanding was that the local *r* would be "moved" implicitly on return.

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T> && a) // move constructor
     :elem{a.elem},sz{a.sz}{
     a.elem=nullptr;
     a.sz=0;
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T> moveVectorAfterAdd(const Vector<T> &  v1, const Vector<T> & v2){
     Vector<T> r =   v1+v2;
     return std::move(r);
     //return r;
}

int main(void) {
     Vector<double> v1(1);
     Vector<double> v2=v1;
     Vector<double> v3=v2;

     Vector<double> v4=moveVectorAfterAdd(v1,v2);

     return 0;
}
```

(As a side note, lldb won't let me even set a break point in the move constructor despite compiling with no optimizations if I don't actually use std::move.)

Any and all clarifications gladly received!

Comment: It doesn't move because "no work is less work than some work" (quote shamelessly stolen from a CPPCon Talk): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: But surely the whole point of move constructors and "implicit" is for just this situation? Why would it NOT move in this instance when we have local, r, and we are returning it as a vector AND a move constructor exists? I'm flummoxed.

Comment: In very unformal wording, anything with a name is an lvalue. `r` is a variable with a name. It's an lvalue. This use case is covered by NRVO which is a compiler optimization which will most likely remove the copy (if you don't use `std::move`).

Comment: @super, so return v1+v2 *should* implicitly move?

Comment: @RichieHH Yes. And since c++17 you have mandatory copy elision (RVO) that guarantees to elide even the move.

Comment: @super, I just tried it and it doesnt. C++ 11 and the move constructor is still optimized out. (That said, I have no idea what RVO is or copy "elision" - there sure are a lot of words to learn ;) I'll get on it). The full code btw, and many thanks for the help: http://ix.io/3yly/cpp

Comment: @RichieHH Prior to c++17 it's a compiler optimization, after c++17 it's guaranteed. For example, if you delete both the copy and move constructors the code will fail to compile, even if the optimized code doesn't actually use it.

Comment: If you are up for some reading, have a look at [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: Aha. I think I'm getting it. It did the equivalent of the "move" automagically - ie the local isnt really a local - it created the object directly into the object v4 ?

Comment: @RichieHH Yes, correct.

Comment: Hi, it because of the missing `noexcept` on the move constructor?

Comment: @super which in turn pretty much reduces the need for move constructors?

Comment: You might test by trying with movable non-copiable types (such as `std::unique_ptr`), so you don't fallback to copy when it is missing, (and you got error in such case).

Comment: @RichieHH I wouldn't phrase it that way. Being able to move a type is still as useful even if it in the specific case of "returning by value from a function" is not always needed.

Comment: @Debashish: it is some methods of `std::vector` which require `noexcept` to use move internally instead of copy.

Comment: @Jarod42, actually I misunderstood the question. `Copy elision` is happening here and the `move` will be overhead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When do you need to explicitly call std::move and when not in cpp?

In short, and technically precise words: Use std::move when you have an lvalue that you want to be an rvalue. More practically: You would want to do that when there is a copy that you want instead to be a move. Hence the name std::move.

In the example, you return an automatic variable. There is no copy that can be avoided by using std::move because in the special case of returning an automatic variable, there will be a move even from an lvalue.

> Here I show the move constructor and the function that I thought would use it. It doesn't.

Just because there is a move in the abstract machine, doesn't necessarily mean that there would be a call to the move constructor. This is a good thing because doing nothing can potentially be faster than calling the move constructor.

This is known as (Named) Return Value Optimization. Or more generally copy elision. Using std::move inhibits this optimization, so not only is it unnecessary in this case, but it is also counter productive.

Comment: I understand a lot more, primarily thanks to the patient comments from @super in the OP, but this helps too, so I'm marking it as the answer. Though I'm not quite sure where the "counterproductive" bit fits. It's all rather a long way from the C with classes I dabbled with in 1999. I'm glad I dont have to juggle C++ using multiple versions of the C++standard.

Comment: Re-reading, I do see where the use of the move would be inefficient in the case that RVO can be utilised by the compiler. I leave this as a separate comment to remind me (and maybe others) where the slight hiccups occur in understanding. Thank you!